# How setup ec2 i3.large to get 475 Gb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have launched `i3.large` which offer about 475Gb for storage (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) but when I invoke `df -h` I got:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.5G   64K  7.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.7G     0 100% /
```

E.g. this instance contains only `22.5`Gb. Why? What does `0.475`Tb refers from intance types table?

Comment: Possibly related: [Mounting a NVME disk on AWS EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45167717/174777)

Answer (score 0):

Try copying a large amount of data there - I'm wondering if it expands. I tried doing a df -h on mine and got small numbers but then I built a 200GB database on it.

Comment: I have copied ~`6.5`Gb from `/dev/xvda1` to `/dev/shm` I again got error about new files creation :(